# Would symmetry positive semi-definite matrix always decomposable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

Given symmetry positive semi-definite matrix $A \in R^{n\times n}$. And $Det(A) \geq 0$.

Would there always exist real matrix $B$, such that $A = B \cdot B^T$?

If so why? Or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is positive. There exists several decompositions like that.

See for example [Cholesky_decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). Another way is to use the fact that a symmetric positive semi-definite real matrix is diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis with non negative eigenvalues. See [symmetric matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix).